# Adding polaris viewer in the android application

Tags: java, android

I am building an app where, when i click a button a pdf file or a ms word file should display within the activity.I do not want to display using third party program like adobe reader,polaris etc.

I searched through many websites and found that library should be used to achieve this.

> But my question is: **Is there any way to install the polaris viewer or adobe viewer in the code of the application itself and when I click the button instead of displaying it outside the activity it should be displayed inside the activity**.

I do not want the user to install adobe reader or polaris viewer seperately.

Comment: Hi, please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . More general stuff about android should be asked here http://android.stackexchange.com/

Comment: my question was about android only

Answer (score 0):

There is really no need to integrate a 'viewer' such as Adobe Reader or Polaris into your application. You can display these documents using Android's standard views:

### Display PDF

If you are supporting API version 21 (Lollipop) onwards **only**, consider using the [PdfRenderer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/pdf/PdfRenderer.html) class. The documentation gives a good example of how to use this:

```
// create a new renderer
 PdfRenderer renderer = new PdfRenderer(getSeekableFileDescriptor());

 // let us just render all pages
 final int pageCount = renderer.getPageCount();
 for (int i = 0; i < pageCount; i++) {
     Page page = renderer.openPage(i);

     // say we render for showing on the screen
     page.render(mBitmap, null, null, Page.RENDER_MODE_FOR_DISPLAY);

     // do stuff with the bitmap

     // close the page
     page.close();
 }

 // close the renderer
 renderer.close();
```

Otherwise, libraries such as [Android PDFView](https://github.com/JoanZapata/android-pdfview) can be used to display PDFs in your application.

### Display .doc

Consider opening a .doc file with a `WebView`

```
 String doc="<iframe src='http://docs.google.com/viewer?url="+doc_url+"&embedded=true'"+
    " width='100%' height='100%' style='border: none;'></iframe>";

        WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.fileWebView); 
        wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        wv.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        wv.loadData( doc , "text/html",  "UTF-8");
```